# Google Maps click event places marker but can't zoom on dlbclick event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need people to be able to click on the map, place a marker, update the input fields, and still be able to dbl click to zoom in more even after the marker is set.

What I have now does everything besides allow a dblclick event to zoom.

```
var map;
var marker = null;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.639, -95.689),
      zoom: 3
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        $("#latcoord").val(event.latLng.lat());
        $("#longcoord").val(event.latLng.lng());

        if (marker) { marker.setMap(null); }


         marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: event.latLng, map: map});

    });


        }  

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't double click work as zoom in per default? If you have problems you can set `disableDoubleClickZoom: false` in your map options. And _This event is fired when the user double-clicks on the map. Note that the click event will also fire, right before this one_

Answer (score 0):

set disableDoubleClickZoom to false
like this

> map.set("disableDoubleClickZoom", false);

Comment: in the initialize function?

Comment: tried it and it helps some but for some reason it only lets me zoom occasionally

Comment: test in other browser

Comment: I am using Chrome, I don't consider it a fix if it only works in some browsers or only one browser.